# "Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1"

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

I'm trying to write an Apex trigger that  makes a field on the Contact called Meeting Date equal to the Meeting Date field on the Opportunity. For some reason I'm getting an error saying "Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1". Which apparently means that the SOQL query isn't pulling any information?

Very new to Apex/Coding so any guidance helps.

Thanks!

```
trigger updateMeetingDate on Contact (before update) {

  List<Opportunity> newOppList = [Select Opportunity.Meeting_Date__c
                  From Opportunity
                  Where Opportunity.Type = 'New Business'
                      And(Opportunity.StageName = 'TQL' OR Opportunity.StageName = 'SAL')
                 ];
   if(Contact.Open_Opportunity_Count__c = 1){
   Contact.Meeting_Date__c = Opportunity.Meeting_Date__c; 
   }            
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You have an assignment expression, using the assignment operator (single equals =) where a Boolean expression is expected.

```
if(Contact.Open_Opportunity_Count__c = 1)
```

You should use the equality operator (double equals ==) instead to test equality.

```
if(Contact.Open_Opportunity_Count__c == 1)
```

See [Understanding Expression Operators](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) for the official documentation.